# Google analytics metrics number of new vs returning customers

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

I use data from google analytics API (v3 and v4). I have access to all metrics.

I need to get the rate of Returning Customers.

So I need to get the number of new purchasers vs. le number of the old purchasers.

My question is: How can I use the google analytics metrics to calculate the returning customer's rate?

Comment: it ils accessible from the UI, in Audiences > Behavior > New vs Returning, you can get access to an e-commerce report that provides you with the revenue per user type.

Comment: this the New vs Returning visitors and not purchasers

Comment: indeed, but in that report, you also have an e-commerce selection that provides you with revenue from New and Returning purchasers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the google analytics v3 API

to calculate the number of new customers, calculate the number of users who made a single transaction during the defined period

- metrics : ga:users,ga:transactions
- dimensions : [EMPTY]
- filters : ga:transactions==1

to calculate the number of new returning customers, calculate the number of users who made more than one transaction during the defined period

- metrics : ga:users,ga:transactions
- dimensions : [EMPTY]
- filters : ga:transactions>1

we can simulate it here
https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/query-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the returning customer rate using Google Analytics, you can take advantage of the newVsReturning dimension. This dimension categorizes users into 'new' (0 previous sessions) or 'returning' (1 or more previous sessions).

link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema